# Chinese string can't be recognized after the ajax request

Tags: javascript, web-services, jquery, cordova, encode

I write an Ajax request to POST the data. The webservice XML information is shown as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"     xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
<AddNewStory xmlns="http://X.X.X.X/StoryForMac/">
  <StoryID>+story_id+</StoryID>
  <UserName>+User_Name+</UserName>
  <Story_CreateTime>+Story__CreateTime+</Story_CreateTime>
  <StoryName>+Story_Name+</StoryName>
</AddNewStory>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webServiceAddNewStoryImgUrl,
            contentType: "text/xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            data: soap_add_new_story_image,     
            success: process_update_pic_success,
            error: process_add_new_img_Error        
        });
```

I get the Chinese string from the text file, assigning it to the variable Story_Name.
After this, I make a request to the webservice,but the Chinese string shows
????????.  No matter what I input, it just shows the Chinese string "?????"....

As I know, the string declared on the webservice(implemented in C#) is encoded as Unicode, and the javascript string is encoded UTF-8(?) as well.
 I can't figure it out why this happened. 

I made a test: I run the debugger on the webservice and input Chinese string directly. This time, it shows correctly !!

 Why this happened?

ps: I create the application based on the Android system and I use PhoneGap API to read the string on the mobile device. 

 Any suggestion??

ANY HELP OR SUGGESTION, PLEASE. I HAVE SPENT SEVERAL DAYS IN THIS ISSUE, TRYING LOTS OF METHOD, BUT ALL IN VAIN.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example Shown @ http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html

-Thanks