# The jquery ajax doesn't work

Tags: jquery, post, character-encoding, urlencode

Here is my $.ajax() code, but I can't make it work.

After I change the form from contentType: `"text/xml ; ",**` 
to `contentType: "text/xml ; charset=UTF-8",`

The request is broken. However, according to the official document: [api/$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), I have to do so,or the charset will be same with the server.

```
var soapRequest_add_a_new_story_to_db=
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'+
  '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" '+
'xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" '+
     'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'+
  '<soap:Body> '+
    '<AddNewStory xmlns="http://x.x.x.x/StoryForMac/">'+
  '<StoryID>'+story_id+'</StoryID>'+
  '<UserName>' +User_Name+ '</UserName>'+
  '<Story_CreateTime>'+Edit_Time+'</Story_CreateTime>'+
  '<StoryName>'+Story_Name+'</StoryName>'+
'</AddNewStory>'+
'</soap:Body>'+
'</soap:Envelope>'; 



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: webServiceAddNewStoryToDbUrl,
            contentType: "text/xml ; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "xml",    
            data: soapRequest_add_a_new_story_to_db,        
            success: processSuccess,        //If the SOAP connection sucessess, the function: processSuccess() will be called.  
            error: processError     
        });
```

My another relevant emergent issue [Chinese Character doesn't appear.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270123/chinese-string-cant-be-recognized-after-the-ajax-request) is similar to this one, if available, please take a look.

**UPDATE:**

Please read [this part of the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/),(ctr+f, jump to "processData").

I think my data is already a query string so that I ignore the option:processData.  The doc says: *"If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false."* But my **soapRequest_add_a_new_story_to_db** is not a DOMDocument. And what's the definition of "non-processed" data? Please give explain and relative reference document.

Comment: What is the error message and/or response you get?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013111/jquery-ajax-consume-soap-web-service

Comment: @rene           I'll try on it now.

Comment: @rene           God... Thank you, I don't know how to thank u.
I search for several days to address this issue. But I don't know why can't I just find the post you provided for me? Why? Why? Why? Why didn't I find the post you got. Do you have the habit to collect the answers to similar problems? I just don't want it to happen again and again. Please tell me how and why you know to address the issue. Please...

Comment: @rene     I'll update my question to ask why should I have to add this option, since I still can't figure out what the doc tells about, hoping you can give the answer so that I can give you the credit.

Comment: Google to the rescue: "soap calls from jquery"

Comment: Why do you use the keyword "soap calls from jquery", I just use ajax jquery, soap request, and as I found the relative posts are not similar. I ignore them... I won't ever to give the key word "soap calls from jquery"...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19675/discussion-between-rene-and-stallman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your ajax call you have to prevent the processing of your data. You basically tell jquery: "don't touch my request and response data I know what I'm doing."
The data in your request var is a valid soap message as is, so you want to prevent that jquery tries to convert it (which it will do for json or xml data).

```
  $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: webServiceAddNewStoryToDbUrl,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"UTF-8\"",
        dataType: "xml",   
        processData: false, 
        data: soapRequest_add_a_new_story_to_db,        
        success: processSuccess, //If the SOAP connection sucessess, the function: processSuccess() will be called.  
        error: processError     
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean that the "data" is not processed till it receives the "dataType"? Only after it gets the "datatype", it knows how to analyse the "data"?

Comment: So in most time, the data is unprocessed.

Comment: jquery tries to give you based on the datatype an domdocument or a javascript object structure. processData = false give you a plain string that you have to handle by your self, write your own code etc.

Comment: You mean I set processData = false so that I can create my own data type?

Comment: Thank u so much! But can you give me the references you just took, so that I can deeply understand it. Thanks.